# why sudo create directories in wrong permission drwxr-sr-x?

Tags: sudo, sudoers

I run sudo on ArchLinux(on x86_64) and Fedora(on sh4 cpu). They behavior different.

```
sudo mkdir x
ls -l x
```

- It shows **drwxr-xr-x root root x** on ArchLinux.
- But shows **drwxr-sr-x root mygroup x** on Fedora sh4.

I'm wonder how to fixed this problem.  I've tried put /etc/sudoers on Fedora, but it still create on wrong permission.

```
Defaults umask=0022
```

Comment: What does `sudo umask` return, and what are the permissions of the parent directory where you are creating the subdirectory?

Comment: Thank you Paul. my root use 'busybox sh'.  So, sudo umask will display unkown command.  I guess you may found my problem, it is caused by the parent directory.